# Unable to start tomcat 9 with flowable war- PUBLIC.ACT_DE_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK error

Tags: tomcat9, flowable

I have downloaded flowable from flowable.com/open-source and placed the flowable-ui.war and flowable-rest.war in tomcat 9.0.52 webapps folder.
When i start server after some time i can see below line repeating in  cmd and server getting stopped.
SELECT LOCKED FROM PUBLIC.ACT_DE_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
2021-08-13 20:45:05.818  INFO 8316 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Waiting for changelog lock.

Why is this issue occurring I have not made any changes?

Answer (score 0):

The message

> l.lockservice.StandardLockService : Waiting for changelog lock.

occurs when Flowable waits for the lock for the DB changes to be released.
If that doesn't happen it means that some other node has picked up the log and not released it properly. I would suggest you manually deleting the lock from that table (ACT_DE_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK).

In addition to that, there is no need to run both flowable-ui.war and flowable-rest.war. flowable-rest.war is a subset of flowable-ui.war.